# NuGet package referencing issues in new Nuget Class Library template in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-core

I've been working with the pre-release version of VS2015 recently which gave the option of a "ASP.NET 5 Class Library" which has since changed in RTM to simply "Class Library (Package)" With the description `PREVIEW - A project template for creation a class library as a NuGet package that can target any platform`

I recently created one of these new Class Library projects and added in into a solution which also included an ASP.NET 5 project. I used the Package manager console to add in references to Entity Framework 7 to both projects which worked fine, adding the correct text into the project.json files in both projects (the Reference section in VS also updated accordingly). But when trying to add `using Microsoft.Data.Entity;` to my Class Library project I cannot reference it at all. It works fine in the ASP.NET project.

Intellisense gives me options for 'Microsoft.CSharp' and one other namespace, but not 'Data'. I've tried creating an entirely new solution from scratch but this still hasn't helped.

I also tried adding references to the dnx XUnit stuff to the project as per their website's guidelines but these did not work either.

**EDIT: I think the problem lies somewhere with the `dotnet` Target Framework Moniker(TFM) which looks to have been introduced in DNX SDK 1.0.0-beta5 as there are not issues when using dnx451 in 1.0.0-beta4**

Comment: is there a version listed in project.json or global.json ? I'm assuming its the one that shipped with in VS2015

Comment: The class library template does not contain a global.json file, just the project.json file. It does contain a version section which is 1.0.0-*, which refers to the project itself rather than anything it references. Going into the properties I can see that the DNX SDK Version is 1.0.0-beta5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found a post on github from the author of xunit, Brad Wilson who states that currently the dotnet TFM doesn't work as you would expect and that the `dnx451` and `dnxcore50` are better TFM's to target.

[image: Brad Wilson's comment]

[Link to comment](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/559#issuecomment-135521748)

Answer (score 3):

I just went through the process of adding 2 projects. A class library and an mvc 6 project. I could duplicate your issue. To fix it I edited the class library project.json and changed the property under "frameworks" from
**dotnet** to the 2 frameworks **dnx451** and **dnxcore50** as is found in the web project. Hope this helps.

Comment: I was considering doing this too. However, I shouldn't have to as the dotnet property should be the one we use according to Microsoft. I'd rather they fix it as it looks like they want us using dotnet by default going forward and I don't want to be reverting to the old way of doing it. But thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 1):

Delete all files in %userprofile%\.dnx\packages and then in the VS2015 Package Manager window execute "dnu restore".

Comment: I tried this and it fixed the issue introduced by following deebo dnu restore below but I'm still unable to access any of the EF classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try open a command line terminal in the directory containing Class Library's project.json and type

```
dnu restore
```

Comment: I tried this and it's actually now giving me a lot of errors about namespaces such as system and microsoft etc, it's made it worse!

Comment: Well that could be more information. Broken is broken really. https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/53 and https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/55 mention namespace changes so maybe its referencing the wronger version. What does it say is default if you run "dnvm list"